# Nesting grid is not working, but when hard coded its ok

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, grid

I want to create grid for scheduler, right now I am using
`import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2';`
All I want to do is to fix column space so that it looks like in this picture with OK cells:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My problem is that I am unable to set such widths on the row above.
Here is the code:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Weekly Schedule</h2>
      <div className="schedule-grid">
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <Grid container rowSpacing={1.4} columnSpacing={1.9} columns={44}>
            <Grid xs={2}>
              <Item>`</Item>
            </Grid>
            {weekDays.map((day) => (
              <Grid xs={6}>
                <Item>{day}</Item>
              </Grid>
            ))}
            <Grid xs={2}>
              <Item>D</Item>
            </Grid>
            {dates.map((date) => (
              <Grid xs={6}>
                <Item>{date}</Item>
              </Grid>
            ))}
            {renderRow("8:00", tableCells[0])}

            //HARD CODE
            <Grid xs={2}>
              <Item>8:00</Item>
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}>
              <Grid xs={3}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={3}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>

            </Grid>

            <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}>
              <Grid xs={6}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>


            <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>OK</Item>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

and the `renderRow` function:

```
  const renderRow = (time: string, blocks: Block[][]) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Grid xs={2}>
          <Item>{time}</Item>
        </Grid>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map(element => (
          <React.Fragment key={element}>
            {/* <Grid xs={6} container columnSpacing={a} columns={6}> */} //commented
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>{element}</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>{element}</Item>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={2}>
                <Item>{element}</Item>
              </Grid>
            {/* </Grid> */} //commented
          </React.Fragment >
        ))}
      </>
    );
  };
```

If I uncomment the code in this function to be exactly the same as in hard-coded version I end up with this:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I have no idea why does it do not want to work, I tried a lot of things and nothing worked out. I am struggling with it very badly. I will greatly appreciate any help!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar3Uq.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO0um.png